# facebook php sdk api query

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a Facebook Graph API query to return names of my friends if I provide a list of IDs? I know I can do it separately for each friend but obviously this would be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way to get the names from `friends` connection of user

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name
```

Using PHP-SDK this can be done like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(...));
$facebook->api('/me/friends', array(
  'fields'=>'name'
));
```

If you want to pass the `ids` of users to get their names it may be done so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=name&ids=userid_1,userid_2,userid_n
```

Or the same using PHP-SDK:

```
$array_of_user_ids = array(4,123,/*etc*/);
$facebook = new Facebook(array(...));
$facebook->api('/', array(
  'ids'=>implode(',', $array_of_user_ids);
  'fields'=>'name'
));
```

Comment: What if there are 2 fields needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends
```

It returns friends names with their ids.